# I can't turn Ubuntu 16.04 in fullscreen mode using VirtualBox 6.0.4

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed "Seed Ubuntu 16.04 32bit" on VirtualBox and the VirtualBox Guest Additions 6.0.4 but i cant view the machine in fullscreen mode. What can i do?
My main system is Win10 build 18362

Answer (score 1):

Right click on desktop and go to "**display settings**". There set **Resolution** to **1920:1200 (16:10)**. Click on **Apply**. Then a popup will appear, click **keep configurations**.[image]

Answer (score 0):

enter in ubunto config -> divice -> and change the resolution